# i am not getting the dropdown-menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Code Below

```css
.drop-content{
  display:none;
}
.one:hover .drop-content{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <h1> Drop-down menu</h1>
  <p>this .html file is an example of a drop-menu.</p></div>
  <span class="one">hover over here to see the drop</span>               
  <div class="drop-content">
  <p>hello,there</p>
</div>
```

I am not getting the drop-menu, 
I have tried div class to but not getting the results, please help me out

Answer (score 0):

```
       .one:hover .drop-content{
       display:block;}
```

suggests that `.drop-content` is a **child** of `.one` *which it isn't*...it's a sibling.

So use a sibling selector

```
       .one:hover + .drop-content{
       display:block;}
```

```css
.drop-content{
  display:none;
}
.one:hover + .drop-content{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
.drop-content{ display:none; } .one:hover .drop-content{ display:block; }
<div class="menu">
  <h1> Drop-down menu</h1>
  <p>this .html file is an example of a drop-menu.</p>
</div>
<span class="one">hover over here to see the drop</span>
<div class="drop-content">
  <p>hello,there</p>
</div>
```